# Set nodeValue content html in DOMDocument

Tags: php

I have created new element with dom object:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$link = $doc->createElement('a'); 
$link->setAttribute('href', '/#');
$link.nodeValue = '<b>Text</b>';
$html = $this->doc->saveHTML();
```

This variable "$html" contains content:

```
<a href="/#">&lt;b&gt;Text&lt;/b&gt;</a>
```

I want to output:

```
<a href="/#"><b>Text</b></a>
```

How can I set "nodeValue" correctly?
Is it possible to do it this way?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using a [DOMDocumentFragement](http://docs.php.net/DOMDocumentFragment) and it's [appendXML()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php) method

```
<?php
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$link = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('html'))
    ->appendChild( $doc->createElement('body') )
    ->appendChild( $doc->createElement('a') );
$link->setAttribute('href', '/#');


$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML('<b>text</b>');
$link->appendChild($fragment);


echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

prints

```
<html><body><a href="/#"><b>text</b></a></body></html>
```

Comment: How do I add the attributes in any fragment?